# How to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services from SSMS remotely

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

My SQL Server Analysis Services is hosted and accessed in local network. I am trying to connect to SSAS remotely from SSMS within the network. But I do not see an option to connect via userame and password. There is only option for "Windows authentication" and 2 for Azure, which we do not use.

[image]

How can I overcome this and connect to the SSAS using my local username and password from the SSAS server?

Answer (score 1):

SSAS [is just available through windows authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/authentication-methodologies-supported-by-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions). You can use domain user (Active Directory) for connecting to remote SSAS server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Runas in windows CMD command line.

Run:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms"
```

where the `domain` must be changed with your domain and `username` with your username connection. Also, change `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\ssms` with your `ssms` correct path.

Answer (score 0):

When I registered my login username (NOT domain user) and password of my local PC on the SSAS server's Windows, I was able to connect to the SSAS with SSMS remotely.